# Laravel 5.7 using same url action for insert and update with @yield in blade template

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I am using laravel 5.7 and I am using one form for inserting and updating. In form action I want to use @yield() for laravel route to get the id for updation. Every thing is fine but I can't use @yield() method. Here is my code, problem is only in action of the form.

```
   <form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ url('/todo/@yield('editId')') }}" method="post">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        @section('editMethod')
            @show
        <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" value="@yield('editTitle')" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Body" name="body" rows="5" id="textarea">@yield('editBody')</textarea>
                    <br>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

I have also checked with single and double quotes.

```
 action="/todo/@yield('editid')"
```

When I use simple this method then after submitting it redirects me to localhost and with an error page not found. In laravel 5.4 it works. but not in laravel 5.7. Any help would be appreciated Thanks

Here is my edit.blade.php from where I am using the @section and @yield

```
  @extends('Todo.create')

  @section('editId',$item->id)
  @section('editTitle',$item->title)
  @section('editBody',$item->body)

  @section('editMethod')
   {{ method_field("PUT") }}
  @endsection
```

Controller store edit and update methods are

```
   public function store(Request $request)
{
    $todo = new todo;
    $this->validate($request,[
        'body'=>'required',
        'title'=>'required|unique:todos',
    ]);
    $todo->body = $request->body;
    $todo->title = $request->title;
    $todo->save();
    return redirect("todo");
}

 public function edit($id)
{  
    $item = todo::find($id);
    return view("Todo.edit",compact('item'));
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $todo = todo::find($id);
    $this->validate($request,[
        'body'=>'required',
        'title'=>'required',
    ]);
    $todo->body = $request->body;
    $todo->title = $request->title;
    $todo->save();
    return redirect("/todo");
}
```

Comment: `@section` and `@yield` is intended for HTML sections. Don't use it for simple string variables. Just pass the variables themselves

Comment: the editId I am referencing from edit.balde.php, from where I am passing Id like this $item->id, this is the id coming and i want to pass it to the route for updation

Comment: I have never seen the use o`@yield` at url there is no way of store and update using same url because laravel stores data using `store` method in controller and updates  data using `edit` and `update` method.

Comment: Please show us your controller and the route with which you are opening this blade file too. I'd like to answer this a bit more detailed but it would be easier with some more code. You clearly misunderstood the concept of blade directives.

Comment: I am agree with you but i have used edit and store and update methods in controller am i have fetched the data and everything, see I have updated the question

Comment: How did you name the file which contains the first code (in which you use yield)?

Comment: Okay let me show controller, i am using resource routes, you might know about that

Comment: I have used like this @section('editId',$item->id)

Comment: Route::resource('todo','todocontroller'); it contains all the routes

Comment: Please edit your question and don't post it as comments. The most important part would be the controller code.

Comment: Check updated code, controller coded is added @TimSch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the OP actual question you would need to do

```
@section('editId', "/$item->id") or @section('editId', '/'.$item->id')

{{ url('/todo') }}@yeild('editId')
```

But much better to do

```
{{ url('/todo/'.(isset($item) ? $item->id : '')) }}
```

Or for PHP >= 7

```
{{ url('/todo/'.($item->id ?? '')) }}
```

Comment: `{{ url('/todo') }}/@yield('editId')` this works for me but it works for update not for insertion and when I remove this / and put it with todo/ then it works for insertion but not for updation

Comment: @AkhtarMunir updated answer to fix that issue. If insert you can leave the editId section out or put in an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

As apokryfos already mentioned - @yield is thought to make reusing your templates easier.
If you simply want to determine (for example) which action should be called afterwards you should better do something like that:

```
@extends('Todo.create')
<form class="form-horizontal" action="/todo/{{ isset($item) ? $item->id : '' }}" method="post">
        @if( ! isset($item))
           {{ method_field("PUT") }}
        @else
           {{ method_field("PATCH") }}

        {{csrf_field()}}
        <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" value="{{ isset($item) ? $item->title : '' }}" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Body" name="body" rows="5" id="textarea">{{ isset($item) ? $item->body : '' }}</textarea>
                    <br>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
</form>
```

Also as I remember the method field should always come first to make sure it's recognized correctly. Additionally you shouldn't need url() to generate the url I think.
No need for a second blade. Simply inject the variables directly into the template and make sure they are set before you access them. I didn't try it but I'd think that it should work.

Comment: thanks bro but it doesn't work for me because it land me on localhost, i must use url with that like $justrusty mentioned